# PowerShell and ITextSharp - create new PDF based on template

Tags: pdf, powershell, replace, itext

I am using ITextSharp and PowerShell to create a PDF document.

I want to be able to load an existing template PDF file which ideally has placeholders and then replace the placeholders with values I supply.

Then I want to save the document with the changes as a new PDF.

Is this possible?

Right now here is the code I have for creating a PDF

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("c:\\itextsharp.dll")
[void][iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter]::GetInstance($Doc, [System.IO.File]::Create("c:\existing.pdf") )
# Need to edit $Doc (replace values, add elements) then save as new file
$Doc.Close()
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: Hopefully those *placeholders* are AcroForm form fields as assumed by @JayRiggs in his answer. Otherwise, i.e. if the *placeholders* are part of the text content of the pages, it can be very difficult (and probably not feasible from Powershall) to do such replacements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll use the `AcroFields.SetFields` method to specify the values you want in each of the fields in your fillable PDF form:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($iTextSharpLibFullname)

$reader = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader($templateFileFullname)

$stamper = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper($reader, 
                                                     [System.IO.File]::Create($outputFileFullname)) 

$stamper.AcroFields.SetField('Field1_Name', 'Field1_Value')
$stamper.AcroFields.SetField('Field2_Name', 'Field2_Value')
#etc. for each field in your form...     

$stamper.Close()
```

Where:
`$iTextSharpLibFullname` is a reference to iTextSharp.dll
`$templateFileFullname` is the name of your fillable PDF template form
`$outputFileFullname` is the name of the PDF you'll create